# meson only boolean options - reproducible builds

Tags: meson-build

Fragment of meson_options.txt:
`option('name', type: 'boolean', value: true, description: 'Test name')`

Fragment of meson.build:

```
conf = configuration_data()
deps = []
conf.set('NAME', get_option('name'))
if conf.get('NAME')
    deps += dependency('name')
endif
```

I want `meson configure /tmp/ -Dname=false` to skip check for dependency name,
but if I do not install name-dev, meson fails with ERROR: Dependency "name" not found.
In meson_options.txt are only boolean options.
I want simple reproducible builds: `meson .. -Dname=false -Dname2=true ...`
If option is false skip dependency, if option is true, and dependency is not found, fail with error.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I executed meson twice, once:
`meson /tmp .`
and next time:
`meson configure /tmp -Dname=false`

Error was from the first meson.